# Change div background after certain amounts of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, addclass

I have a script that shows the amount of clicks on a button and I want to change the background image of another div after a certain amount of clicks, in this case 5. At the moment the click amount works fine but the other part wont react to it. The second code works if I manually type 5 as the starting value for `#click`.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#clicks').html(function (i, val) {
        return val * 1 + 1
    });
});

if ($('#clicks').html() == 5) {
    $("#first").addClass('red');
}
```

```html
<div id="clicks">0</div>
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="button">click</div>
```

```css
#first {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}
.red {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I might add here that I never knew that adding a class with a different background-image doesn't replace the previous one(?) or is it that I used the background-tag instead of background-image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the value after each click modification. also you should compare the returned value with string:

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
     $('#clicks').html(function (i, val) {
       return val * 1 + 1
     });
    //check for new value
    if ($('#clicks').html() == "5") {
      $("#first").addClass('red');
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! Took a while to apply with the actual problem, but anyway it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('div').click(function() {
    if (count++ == 5) {
      $(this).addClass('red');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value and check if it's 5 within the click function.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#clicks').html(function (i, val) {
        val++;
        if (val == 5)
            $("#first").addClass('red');
        return val;
    });
});
```

You can also change it every 5 clicks by using the modulus and toggleclass.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#clicks').html(function (i, val) {
        val++;
        if (val % 5 == 0)
            $("#first").toggleClass('red');
        return val;
    });
});
```